# Notification Code added in Service but not working

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I'm added Notification code in my android service.

Tried
[Notifications Code in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763330/notifications-code-in-android)

```
        Log.e("TAG","In 2");
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Restarter.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        notificationBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("sdjshfjnds");
        inboxStyle.addLine("sdjjsdfn");
        notificationBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I m getting log message but not notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the old answer, it's 2015 year. Now it's not actual. Please check the actual documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification